# What is this little leaved plant?

Tags: identification, indoors, houseplants

The stem of this plant goes curling up like a creeper plant. It has small leaves. Not seen any flower yet, so not sure if it flowers or not.

[image]

Zoomed-in:
[image]

**New added pic:** 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a climber of some sort, not sure what. When it's bigger, or flowers, its identity might be more apparent - at the moment, the leaves are reminiscent of a Jasmine variety, but not sure it is one of that family.

Comment: Yes, it is a climber. I am waiting if it flowers..! Thanks @Bamboo

Comment: I don't think it is a jasmine or at least it doesn't resemble the compound leaf jasmines I am familiar with.

Comment: I highly agree that this is a Jasminum of a sort. Try J. grandiflorum, J. polyanthum or J. officinale. The bright green stems fortify my belief.

Comment: @Brenn I think you've got it, it seems most like J. grandiflorum, but this question was so long ago now it must have become self evident which plant it is by now

Comment: Lol. I didn't realize how old this question was until you pointed it out. Oh well. For posterity! Nice work @Bamboo, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a "bignonia", perennial climber plant, many many orange flowers like trumpets in group, during all the summer, no smells.

Orange colour is normal typical color, other colours are from gardeners.

Clay soil, no particularly water, very strong plant.

Bignonia Capreolata - Genus Bignoniacee - Family Catalpa

[image: bignonia image]
[image: here]
<sub>(source: [wildflower.org](https://www.wildflower.org/image_archive/640x480/JAM6151/6151_IMG01793.JPG))</sub>
.

Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignonia_capreolata) for link.

Comment: Still it didn't flowered yet, But mostly it is flowering plant, I remember while buying it. Also as you say "Bignonia", you could be right but I am not getting any particular match with its different types. Try if you could clearify more. Any reference would be a plus.

Comment: since plants are classified from flowers, you have just to wait

Comment: It seems to me to be that, why the top of new branches spring from two leaves. The new branches of jasmine and wisteria, the most similar to that, make long files to grimp around, like that: [link to image](https://www.google.es/search?q=bignonia+capreolata&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mm5OUdmyGsXAhAfs0ICoCA&ved=0CDoQsAQ&biw=1047&bih=860)

Comment: it grimps such grapes [way of grimping](http://www.discoverlife.org/mp/20p?see=I_EHCP1606)

Comment: [bignonia - image od grimping](http://tcf.bh.cornell.edu/users/robbin/5_6_11/upload418/DSCN6643.JPG); [link](http://tcf.bh.cornell.edu/imgs/robbin/r/Bignoniaceae_Bignonia_capreolata_38965.html)

Answer (score -1):

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Podranea_ricasoliana_(Pink_Trumpet_Vine)_in_Hyderabad_W_IMG_5685.jpg
color is usually orange--this is a rampant vine that will cover a telephone pole in less than a year, people love the flowers but to me it is too invasive

http://elpasonovicegardener.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/my-trumpet-vine/

Comment: Hi, you could be right, how are you sure? as the leaves doesn't matches up. so I am not able to decide. If you closely look to images I have given, many places shows leaf-trio near where leaf ends i.e. three leaves combined together.

Comment: Yes it could be. Which is genus and family? Sometime plants of same genetic family are classified under different names.

Comment: ![vew image - 6th raw from top](https://www.google.es/search?q=bignonia&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=t2lVUYSwGuae7AbKsoDAAg&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=1047&bih=860#imgrc=_). There are many different types. And not always scientists agree about classification. See when you have to classify mushrooms. In these cases, flowers can help. Other way, you just have a genetic text.

Comment: ![bignonia ricasoliana](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Bignonia_ricasoliana_Flower_Closeup_TorreLaMata.jpg) [as says the page](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bignonia_ricasoliana_Flower_Closeup_TorreLaMata.jpg) but also Podranea ricasoliana. They seem the same plant. Classification is always difficult, as without a genetic inspection you never can be sure.

Comment: [bignonia ricasoliana](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bignonia_ricasoliana_Flower_Closeup_TorreLaMata.jpg) just different varieties

Answer (score -1):

It IS in the Bigonia family. Exactly what genus or species, I can't tell yet. I think you should winter it next year (2nd to last paragraph).

If you're curious as to how I've IDed it as such - it's an odd pinnately compound leafed woody climbing vine with >5 leaflets per leaf. That's the Bigonia family.

Most Bigonias like to die back in the winter.  They can be indoor plants, but you'll have to stay well on top of pruning to keep them looking good.

I have about 400 vertical sq ft of Trumpet Creeper. It's amazing every spring when its main trunk and branches, off of which everything has died and the bark appears dedicated and peeling, explodes back into life.

I can't speak to your plant specifically, because mine was decades old when I bought my house. Younger plants have distinctly different growth than older ones.

However, if it's a Bigonia, it's likely  hardy, aggressive (they're not really "invasive" - they're native) and will thrive on neglect.  My vine grows on a concrete retaining wall, in a 1' wide, 20' long patch of the worst clay soil you've seen.  Stuff turns almost cement-like when dry, and that trumpet vine's just chuggin' along, happy as a clam. I've overhauled hundreds of square feet of isolated gardens here, but that patch gets the barest of attention. (A lot of vines are like that. Morning Glory is another example. If you want the saddest looking MGs, be nice to them. If you want 6"/day MGs with insane flowers - abuse and ignore them.)

On wintering:
Its green, woody stem - that's your plant asking for dormancy. Woody plants need their winter cycle.  You can help them out and mulch around them, or if in a pot, move them somewhere the temperature doesn't go above 50 degrees and they still get some sunlight. But almost without exception, woody plants need their seasonal cycle.

One final bit: if you say "Bigonia", people will probably hear "Begonia", so just say " Trumpet Vine of some kind" so folks won't think you're nutty.  GL!